# UPDATE SET N + 1 equal to a row

Tags: mysql, mariadb, update

Problem: I need help implementing N+1
WHEN a2 = "Z" then check if the next row number (a1 + 1) has a2 = "Z" ...if this is the case 
 THEN replace the (a1+1) row --> a2 = "Y" .

[MariaDB fiddle](https://sqlize.online/s/R)

Attempt below: obviously there is a syntax error below, I really don't know how to go about how to find the solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
UPDATE a SET CASE 
WHEN a2 = "X" 
AND (a1 + 1) = (a2 = "Z")  
THEN a2 = "Y" END
```

---

Input Table: 2 columns (no iteration)

```
+====+====+
| a1 | a2 |
+====+====+
| 1  | X  |
+----+----+
| 2  | Z  |
+----+----+
| 3  | X  |
+----+----+
| 4  | Y  |
+----+----+
| 5  | Z  |
+----+----+
| 6  | X  |
+----+----+
| 7  | Y  |
+----+----+
```

Desired Result: 2 columns (no iteration)

```
+====+====+
| a1 | a2 |
+====+====+
| 1  | X  |
+----+----+
| 2  | Y  |
+----+----+
| 3  | X  |
+----+----+
| 4  | Y  |
+----+----+
| 5  | Z  |
+----+----+
| 6  | X  |
+----+----+
| 7  | Y  |
+----+----+
```

[MariaDB Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=516672f66393c83b38a400d741d5aa87)

Comment: New question posted here: [Update Set N + 1 equal to a row with iteration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/294481/update-set-n-1-equal-to-a-row-with-iteration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join the right Sub Select, where your rules apply

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `a` (
>   `a1` int(20) NOT NULL,
>   `a2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> --
>
> INSERT INTO `a` (`a1`,  `a2`) VALUES
> (1,  'X'),
> (2, 'Z'),
> (3, 'X'),
> (4, 'Y'),
> (5, 'Z'),
> (6, 'X'),
> (7, 'Y');
>
>
>
>
>
> select * from a order by a1;
> ```
>
> ```
> a1 | a2
> -: | :-
>  1 | X 
>  2 | Z 
>  3 | X 
>  4 | Y 
>  5 | Z 
>  6 | X 
>  7 | Y
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  a1+1 as col1, CASE 
> WHEN a2 = "X" 
> AND (SELECT a2 FROM a WHERE t1.a1+1 = a1)   = "Z"
> THEN "Y" ELSE NULL END as col2 from a t1 order by a1;
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | col2
> ---: | :---
>    2 | Y   
>    3 | null
>    4 | null
>    5 | null
>    6 | null
>    7 | null
>    8 | null
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE a 
> INNER JOIN (SELECT  a1+1 as col1, CASE 
> WHEN a2 = "X" 
> AND (SELECT a2 FROM a WHERE t1.a1+1 = a1)   = "Z"
> THEN "Y" ELSE NULL END as col2 from a t1 order by a1) t2 ON a.a1 = t2.col1 AND t2.col2 IS NOT NULL
> SET a2 = col2
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from a order by a1;
> ```
>
> ```
> a1 | a2
> -: | :-
>  1 | X 
>  2 | Y 
>  3 | X 
>  4 | Y 
>  5 | Z 
>  6 | X 
>  7 | Y
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=516672f66393c83b38a400d741d5aa87)*

A Version with gaps would look like this

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `a` (
>   `a1` int(20) NOT NULL,
>   `a2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> --
>
> INSERT INTO `a` (`a1`,  `a2`) VALUES
> (1,  'X'),
> (3, 'Z'),
> (4, 'X'),
> (5, 'Y'),
> (6, 'Z'),
> (7, 'X'),
> (8, 'Y');
>
> select * from a order by a1;
> ```
>
> ```
> a1 | a2
> -: | :-
>  1 | X 
>  3 | Z 
>  4 | X 
>  5 | Y 
>  6 | Z 
>  7 | X 
>  8 | Y
> ```

> ```
> WITH cte As (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as rn from a order by a1)
> SELECT (SELECT a1 FROM cte WHERE rn = t1.rn+1) as col1, CASE 
> WHEN a2 = "X" 
> AND (SELECT a2 FROM cte WHERE t1.rn+1 = rn)   = "Z"
> THEN "Y" ELSE NULL END as col2 from cte t1 order by rn;
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | col2
> ---: | :---
>    3 | Y   
>    4 | null
>    5 | null
>    6 | null
>    7 | null
>    8 | null
> null | null
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE a 
> INNER JOIN (WITH cte As (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as rn from a order by a1)
> SELECT (SELECT a1 FROM cte WHERE rn = t1.rn+1) as col1, CASE 
> WHEN a2 = "X" 
> AND (SELECT a2 FROM cte WHERE t1.rn+1 = rn)   = "Z"
> THEN "Y" ELSE NULL END as col2 from cte t1 order by rn) t2 ON a.a1 = t2.col1 AND t2.col2 IS NOT NULL
> SET a2 = col2
> ```

> ```
> select * from a order by a1;
> ```
>
> ```
> a1 | a2
> -: | :-
>  1 | X 
>  3 | Y 
>  4 | X 
>  5 | Y 
>  6 | Z 
>  7 | X 
>  8 | Y
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=ff66a2956d36338a946552b045753932)*

Comment: My gut says that those solutions are overly complex.  I challenge you to simplify them.

Comment: @RickJames, they are fine for this solution, the window function solution as Verace posted them are much simpler but aren't faster. The only option is to copy verace answer, but as it is posted aalready and please if you have another siltion make your own answer

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use the window function `LAG`. Something like:

```
update a 
   set a2 = 'Y'
where exists (
  select 1 from (
      select a1, a2, lag(a2) over (order by a1) as lag_a2 
      from a
  ) as t 
  where t.a2 = 'Z' 
    and t.lag_a2 = 'X'
  and t.a1 = a.a1
);
```

If the current a2 is 'Z' and the previous one is 'X', the row should be updated